# How can you get a reflect.Type instance of an struct without physically creating the struct?

Tags: optimization, reflection, go

I want to create a registry of struct types to enable dynamic loading of solutions to 'Project Euler' problems. My current solution however requires the struct to first be created and zeroed before it's type can be registered:

```
package solution

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

type Solution interface {
    Load()
    Solve() string
}

type SolutionRegister map[string]reflect.Type

func (sr SolutionRegister) Set(t reflect.Type) {
    fmt.Printf("Registering %s\n", t.Name())
    sr[t.Name()] = t
}

func (sr SolutionRegister) Get(name string) (Solution, error) {
    if typ, ok := sr[name]; ok {
        sol := reflect.New(typ).Interface().(Solution)
        return sol, nil
    }
    return nil, errors.New("Invalid solution: " + name)
}

var solutionsRegistry = make(SolutionRegister)

func Register(sol Solution) {
    solutionsRegistry.Set(reflect.TypeOf(sol).Elem())
}

func Load(s string) Solution {
    sol, err := solutionsRegistry.Get(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error loading solution  %s (%s)\n", s, err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
    sol.Load()
    return sol
}

type DummySolution struct {
    data [100 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024]uint8
}

func (s *DummySolution) Load() {
}

func (s *DummySolution) Solve() string {
    return ""
}

func Init() {
    Register(&DummySolution{})
}
```

In this example the type of 'DummySolution struct' is registered inside the Init() function. This structure is purposefully absurdly large to illustrate the problem.

Is there a way I could access the type of DummySolution and other Solutions without having to create an instance of the structure beforehand?

Comment: `reflect.TypeOf((*DummySolution)(nil)).Elem()` I think.

Comment: @twotwotwo you should just put that as an answer.

Comment: @twotwotwo, Thanks, that works perfectly.

Comment: Just a suggestion that might improve this code: register a factory function rather than the type itself. Then you don't have to bother with any of the reflection.

Comment: @Endophage The Load() function is in essence a factory function. I use reflection to avoid having to maintain a big switch statement every time I add a new solution. The register function allows me to register a class in the same file as it's definition.

Comment: @JansenduPlessis this is what I was suggesting: http://play.golang.org/p/WcLCKuI4HD It achieves exactly the same functionality but is frankly much simpler by avoiding reflection, which is rarely the right answer to a problem. It also decouples your solution name from your struct name. If you wanted to change the struct name in your original version, you'd have to change all the places you `Load`'ed that solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reflect.TypeOf((*DummySolution)(nil)).Elem()`. Making a `nil` pointer doesn't allocate space for the whole struct, and `Elem` (described under the definition of [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type)) gets you from a pointer (or slice, array, channel, or map) to its element type.